# I was trying to run a mysqli_query with multiple inserts but it isnt working

Tags: php, mysql, post, mysqli

My code is as below: I am trying to insert into my database with multiple inserts at once with  a mysqli_query, how do I go about it?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  questions (exam_type, questions, option_a, option_b,  option_c, answer) 
        VALUES  ('$q_type', '$q1', '$q1a', '$q1b', '$q1c', '$q1answer' );
        INSERT INTO  questions (exam_type, questions, option_a, option_b,  option_c, answer) 
        VALUES  ('$q_type', '$q2', '$q2a', '$q2b', '$q2c', '$q2answer' );
        INSERT INTO  questions (exam_type, questions, option_a, option_b,  option_c, answer) 
        VALUES  ('$q_type', '$q3', '$q3a', '$q3b', '$q3c', '$q3answer' );
        INSERT INTO  questions (exam_type, questions, option_a, option_b,  option_c, answer) 
        VALUES  ('$q_type', '$q4', '$q4a', '$q4b', '$q4c', '$q4answer' );
        INSERT INTO  questions (exam_type, questions, option_a, option_b,  option_c, answer) 
        VALUES  ('$q_type', '$q5', '$q5a', '$q5b', '$q5c', '$q5answer' )

";

echo $sql ."<br>";
require "connect.php";

if($results= mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{

    echo "saved successfully";

}
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Well, the answer is quite simple, but I won't answer it right now. First of all, I ask you to edit your question. Format it and bring in some more information, so you'll learn how to ask properly. After you've done that, I'll answer your question. The solution is quite simple.

Comment: Search php string interpolation.

Comment: "but it isnt working" nothing insert? insert only first? what error return? columns of table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL part shoud be like this.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO questions (exam_type, questions, option_a, option_b, option_c, answer) 
        VALUES ('$q_type', '$q1', '$q1a', '$q1b', '$q1c', '$q1answer' ),
               ('$q_type', '$q2', '$q2a', '$q2b', '$q2c', '$q2answer' ), 
               ('$q_type', '$q3', '$q3a', '$q3b', '$q3c', '$q3answer' ),
               ('$q_type', '$q4', '$q4a', '$q4b', '$q4c', '$q4answer' ), 
               ('$q_type', '$q5', '$q5a', '$q5b', '$q5c', '$q5answer' )";
```

The PHP part is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with this Query:

```
INSERT INTO questions (exam_type, questions, option_a, option_b,
    option_c, answer) VALUES ('$q_type', '$q1', '$q1a', '$q1b', '$q1c',
    '$q1answer' ), ('$q_type', '$q2', '$q2a', '$q2b', '$q2c',
    '$q2answer' ), ('$q_type', '$q3', '$q3a', '$q3b', '$q3c',
    '$q3answer' ),('$q_type', '$q4', '$q4a', '$q4b', '$q4c', '$q4answer'
    ),('$q_type', '$q5', '$q5a', '$q5b', '$q5c', '$q5answer' )
```

Answer (score -2):

For multiple statements in a SQL command like this, you should use `mysqli_multi_query`. `mysqli_query` only applies to a single statement.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm being downvoted. There is one time I had to use two inserts with the second one having a `last_insert_id()` and was clueless as to why `mysqli_query` doesn't work. I just thought it would help some people having the same problem, not necessarily like the OP's query. I agree it would be better fixing the query to be one statement only but it was already pointed out, I just added an answer. Would be nice if at least one of the downvoters try to say what they disagree with at least and try to at least correct me or something.